# why is concat skipping a bunch of inner lines?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I want to concat to set of columns (with around 250). The concat seems to be doing what I want except the result skips a bunch of lines and instead I get "...". As this:

```
                  x             y       z           y2      z2
    0   -9959900000  44885.500000  0.0089  1815.450000  0.0117
    1   -9959800000  11256.800000  0.0181  1544.170000  0.0135
    2   -9959700000   1101.210000  0.0267   463.725000  0.0122
    3   -9959600000    122.781000  0.0452   101.574000  0.0133
    4   -9959500000     13.714300  0.0774    22.112800  0.0157
    ..          ...           ...     ...          ...     ...
    225 -9922800000      0.000001  0.7083     0.002167  0.0540
    226 -9922700000      0.000000  0.0000     0.001495  0.0671
    227 -9922600000      0.000000  0.0000     0.000566  0.0823
    228 -9922500000      0.000000  0.0000     0.000185  0.1315
    229 -9922400000      0.000000  0.0000     0.000024  0.3008
```

I tried

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

But no effect. Any ideas?

This is the code:

```
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.width', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
    df1 = pd.read_csv("data1.dat", delimiter=r"\s+",comment='#') # The delimiter is a string of spaces (instead of commas), rows starting with # are ignored
    df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.dat", delimiter=r"\s+",comment='#') # The delimiter is a string of spaces (instead of commas), rows starting with # are ignored
    #df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer') 
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) #axis=1 indicates we want to concatenate columns, and not rows
    df3 = df3.drop("x2", axis=1)
    df3[['x']] = df3[['x']].sub(100000)
    df3[['x']] = df3[['x']].multiply(100000)
    print(df3)
```

Comment: Why are you setting options about columns? The problem is with rows.

Comment: Try changing `display.max_rows`

Comment: Why do you think `concat()` is skipping the lines? This is just affecting the way the df is printed, not the actual contents.

Comment: Oh my!! such a rookie mistake! Yes @Barmar you are right, it is now displaying every row. Thank you!